# Can't find my variable for accessor/mutator method

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program for a homework assignment where on this first class I am making my variables and adding accessor/mutator methods for this but for some reason it can't find my variable of CashBallPick on line 11.  I checked many times and it looks spelled the same way at all places with caps in the correct places.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CashBall
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[4];
    int yourNumbers;
    int CashBallPick;
    public CashBall(int yourNumbers, int CashBallPick)
    {
        this.yourNumbers=yourNumbers;
        this.yourCashBallPick=CashBallPick;
    }
    public int getYourNumbers()
    {
        return yourNumbers;
    }
    public int getCashBallPick()
    {
        return CashBallPick;
    }
    public void setYourNumbers(int yourNumbers)
    {
        this.yourNumbers=yourNumbers;
    }
    public void setCashBallPick(int CashBallPick)
    {
        this.yourCashBallPick=CashBallPick;
    }

}
```

There is also another class that I am making that is the driver class.  I know for normal variables that are written in a different class, lets say a variable called ExampleVariable   if I had a constructor for that and wanted to use that variable in a different class I would go ExampleVariable E1 = new ExampleVariable(info here)
but how would I do that for an array?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the whole class, try changing line 11 to:

```
this.CashBallPick=CashBallPick
```

That should do it. The reason it didn't work before was because your class did not have a variable named "yourCashBallPick".

Edit: line 27 needs the same fix.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably want your constructor like this:

```
public CashBall(int yourNumbers, int yourCashBallPick)
{
    this.yourNumbers=yourNumbers;
    this.yourCashBallPick=yourCashBallPick;
}
```

You're missing the `your` prefix for `yourCashBallPick` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a mix of `CashBallPick` and `this.yourCashBallPick` in the code. You didn't declare `yourCashBallPick` anywhere so maybe:

```
int CashBallPick;
```

Should be

```
int yourCashBallPick;
```

--Dan

Comment: I see what I did now.  I got confused and thought I had to add the "your" part like the "this" part which is wrong and I'm not sure why I thought that.  Must have been paying attention to the above one too much.  I just got rid of the "your".  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is spelled `yourCashBallPick` in some places (such as `setCashBallPick()` and in your constructor) and `CashBallPick` some others (such as `getCashBallPick()`). make it the same in all methods.

And regarding arrays, lets say you want an array of 14 `ExampleVariable`s:

```
ExampleVariable example[] = new ExampleVariable[14];
for (int i=0; i< example.length; i++)
     example[i] = new ExampleVariable(somevalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this line correct?

```
 this.yourCashBallPick=CashBallPick;
```

Is your global variable really declared like this?